# How to get ten, ten items from Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I am trying to load ten items per page in windows phone 7 list box. When I scroll to end of the list box the another 10 items should be loaded. I have try with a simple sting. I have done with that. When I try to load my original observable collection I can not get the 10,10 items.

I have try like this:-

```
    void AddMoreItems()
    {
        int start = items.Count;
        int end = start + 10;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            items.Add("Item " + i);
        }
    }
```

Here I can load 10, 10 items per page.

Now I try to use observable collection:-

```
int end = 10;
int start = 0;
int total = listForLoading.Count;

void AddMoreItems()
{
    if (total > 0)
    {
        int i = start;
        foreach (var item in StudentDetails)
        {
            if (i < end)
            {
                items.Add(new ListBoxWithButtonModel() { FirstName = item.FirstName,LastName = item.LastName,Age = item.Age,PersonImage=item.PersonImage });                       
                i++;
            }
        }
        total = total > 10 ? total - 10 : total - total;
        start = items.Count;
        end = total > 10 ? start + 10 : start + total;
    }
}
```

Here I am getting the same items again and again. I am trying to remove the items from collections after added to the list box. But I am getting error.

Please let me any idea to load 10, 10 items from the observable collection.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you looked into incremental loading? http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/windows-phone-series-incremental-loading/

Comment: I am getting This error: `InvalidOperationException`. No I did not try this.. I will try this link also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `foreach` always starts at the beginning of the list, but you don't start your counter at the beginning of the list. You can simplify your code with:

```
int taken = 0;  // number of items already taken
int totalToTake = listForLoading.Count;

void AddMoreItems()
{
    if (taken >= totalToTake) return;  // all taken

    int i = 0;
    int stopi = taken+10;
    foreach (var item in StudentDetails)
    {
        if (i >= taken && i < stopi)
        {
            // add your item here

            // and then increment the number taken
            taken++;
        }
        ++i;
    }
 }
```

You can simplify that more with:

```
    var itemsToTake = StudentDetails.Skip(taken).Take(10);
    foreach (var item in itemsToTake)
    {
        // add your item here

        // and then increment the number taken
        taken++;
    }
```